# angular2-schema-form Vs angular2-json-schema-form

Tags: angular

Have you validate to use in Architect "`angular2-schema-form`" vs "`angular2-json-schema-form`" ?

I am not able find any strong documentation for both. Please suggest best one.

Answer (score 4):

angular2-json-schema-form (https://github.com/dschnelldavis/angular2-json-schema-form) looks more in development and getting updated frequently. Also supports most of the UI components.